# It is true that the relatively compact open subsets cannot exist in infinite-dimensional normed spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

It is true that the relatively compact open subsets cannot exist in infinite-dimensional normed spaces? Why yes / not?

Can someone,please, explain to me?

Thank you!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a consequence of [Riesz's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma).